# css img:hover working, img:active is not

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, css, image

I have the following code, which displays the images in my table with no border, then an orange border when hovered over:

```
table.test {
}
.test img {
    border: solid 4px transparent;
}
.test img:hover {
    border-color: orange;
}
```

If it try the following, i expect the border to stay orange after click, but it does not

```
.test img:active {
    border-color: orange;
}
```

The images being used are thumbnail size instead of checkboxes.

Any ideas how I can keep the border orange after click?

Comment: I assume, because you didn't tag it, that you aren't looking for a Javascript - **let-alone** - a jQuery answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class called `orangeborder` (or anything, really). Give it the attributes of `border-color:orange;`.

Then you can use jQuery and use:

```
$('img').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('orangeborder');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RnY3z/)

Answer (score 0):

check this  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VivekNadar/C7h39/13/) might help you using simple jquery let you give your output

```
$('.test img').on('click', function(){
        //use jquery css function
     $(this).css({"border-color":"orange"});
 // or   add class .active with your own style
       $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

make your image as block element and add this jquery click event. solved

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but down to not doing web programming for sometime, my understanding is not what it used to be.  Simply put, can anyone tell me how to keep the border orange when the image is clicked?

Comment: @user3036096 you there..?

Answer (score 0):

Images cannot use active. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/selectors.html#selector-active.Wrap it within an anchor and prevent default on the anchor click and change the cursor maybe?